# Electrolytes for Anodization at Home

Tags: everyday-chemistry, electrochemistry, home-experiment

I'm looking into anodization, and all the people doing it seem to have sulfuric acid as their first choice electrolyte, while others use sodium metabisulfate. Having simple access to exactly neither of these, I was wondering.

1. Why is sulfuric acid important?
2. Can I use more accessable (and safer) electrolytes such as vinegar or sodium bicarbonate instead?
3. How much of a difference would it make?

Comment: @EdV, I could possibly obtain sulfuric acid. However, for a simple experiment at home, I'd like to use household chemicals.

Comment: @EdV, that's pretty interesting. However I was thinking more on the lines of aluminum. Also, if even diet coke is usable, there are probably other household chemicals that would work as well (maybe vinegar?).

Comment: @EdV, that's really my question; why is sulfuric acid necessary? Why not any electrolyte?